# Video Player Fill Parent and Image Slider not work on Android TV

Tags: android, image, slider, mpmovieplayercontroller, app-inventor

I created a videowall application in **MIT App Inventor**, the application has been running fine when I test using a mobile phone, but when I run the application on android tv (55 "), there are some things that do not run like on my phone.

1. The video does not appear as I want (fill parent), and also some of the video is not running.
2. the application there is also a slider image, and only the image with the number 6 are shown, the rest do not appear (i have 12 images).

page designer:

[image]

The following application blocks I made:

[image]

[image]

[image]

android tv specifications:

[image]

on Android TV

[image]

Code Source/Reference:

running text => https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mitappinventortest/QyTWdBROPKY

Play Movie & image from sdcard => http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/concepts/images-and-sounds.html  and  http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/videowall.html

autoplay video player => https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/mitappinventortest/aDzNAWi5hnk

Comment: see the answers in your [App Inventor forum thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/-IuuyKRj9z0/hdGmVc3xDgAJ)

Comment: @Taifun, the topics is closed, so i can't reply on that forum.  but regarding question on that forum, i set it responsive.